Python - Update (Re-register) operator each time it called

With the code bellow I want to generate list of files in specific folder and draw them in Popup menu (EnumProperty). It works fine, but I also want to update this list each time I called operator to redraw items in the list, so if you added some .py script file to folder it will be shown in the list.
If you have more relevant proposal to complete this task feel free to provide it, but please, keep code as simple as possible.
import bpy 
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir

#current_dir = bpy.data.filepath.replace(bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath),'')
folder_path = bpy.utils.script_paths_pref()[0]+'\\' # path from <Script Directories>

def update_filelist(): # create file list of directory 
    allfiles_list = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    files_list = [f for f in allfiles_list if '.py' in f]
    print(files_list)
    return(files_list)

def update_enum_items(files_list): # create list of items for EnumProperty
    enum_items = [('OP' + str(i + 1), item, folder_path) for i, item in enumerate(files_list)]
    print(enum_items)
    return(enum_items) 
  
update_filelist()
update_enum_items(update_filelist())

class RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu(bpy.types.Operator): # enum operator
    bl_label = "Run Script from Folder"
    bl_idname = "wm.run_script_from_folder"
    
    preset_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="execute",
        description='Select a .py script',
        items = update_enum_items(update_filelist()) # dynamic 'items' list for enum operator
    )
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):                # dynamic update filelist on invoke
        wm = context.window_manager
        update_filelist()
        update_enum_items(update_filelist())
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
       
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self,'preset_enum')
           
    def execute(self, context):                   # dynamic execute func for enum operator
        files_list = update_filelist()
        for item,i in enumerate(files_list, start=1):
            if self.preset_enum == str('OP' + str(item)):
                filepath = folder_path + i
                # bpy.data.texts.load(filepath)
                exec(compile(open(filepath).read(), filepath, 'exec'))
        
        return {'FINISHED'}    

classes = [RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Hello, the list should be updated every time you run the operator. BTW it's a bit weird to use item as an index enumerator and i as an item enumerator, I would swap both.

Standard answer
items=update_enum_items

In an enumerated property, if you want the item list to be constantly updated, insert a function object into the item.(But do not execute it.)
def update_enum_items(self, context)

Then, for the update function, insert the argument (self,context).(This is the rule.)
That's all.
However, since it is dynamic, the script may become heavy depending on the state.

import bpy 
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir


#current_dir = bpy.data.filepath.replace(bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath),'')
folder_path = join(bpy.utils.script_paths_pref()[0],"addons")

def update_filelist(): # create file list of directory 
    allfiles_list = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    files_list = [f for f in allfiles_list if '.py' in f]
    # test
#    for idx,file in enumerate(files_list,start=1):
#        print(idx,file)
    return(files_list)


def update_enum_items(self, context):  # The callback function must receive two arguments (self, context)

    files_list = update_filelist()
    enum_items = [('OP' + str(i + 1), item, folder_path,"FILE_SCRIPT" ,i ) for i, item in enumerate(files_list)]
    return enum_items

class RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu(bpy.types.Operator):  # enum operator
    bl_label = "Run Script from Folder"
    bl_idname = "wm.run_script_from_folder"
    
    preset_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="execute",
        description='Select a .py script',
        items=update_enum_items  # Specify callback function
    )
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):  # dynamic update filelist on invoke
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
       
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, 'preset_enum')
           
    def execute(self, context):  # dynamic execute func for enum operator
        files_list = update_filelist()
        for item, i in enumerate(files_list, start=1):
            if self.preset_enum == str('OP' + str(item)):
                filepath = join(folder_path, i)
                exec(compile(open(filepath).read(), filepath, 'exec'))
        
        return {'FINISHED'}    

classes = [RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

This should complete the answer, but... (anti-garbled)
By the way, if you are a non-English speaking type (i.e., multi-byte manipulator), Blender seems to have a bug whereby calling an item of an enumerated type from a function before execution will "garble" it.
def get_enum_items(self, context):
    return _enum_items  # Read only

To resolve this method, you must generate the listings in advance.That is what this function does.
def update_enum_items(self, context):
    global _enum_items  # Declare global only in update functions
    files_list = update_filelist()
    _enum_items = [('OP' + str(i + 1), item, folder_path, "FILE_SCRIPT", i) 
                   for i, item in enumerate(files_list)]
    return _enum_items

The technique is to manage the list in a global variable and share it with functions.
def invoke(self, context, event):
    update_enum_items(self, context)
    return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

Since the list is updated only once within INVOKE,
This also improves performance within the popup window.

import bpy 
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir

folder_path = join(bpy.utils.script_paths_pref()[1],"")
_enum_items = []  

def update_filelist():
    allfiles_list = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    files_list = [f for f in allfiles_list if '.py' in f]
    return files_list

def update_enum_items(self, context):
    global _enum_items  # Declare global only in update functions
    files_list = update_filelist()
    _enum_items = [('OP' + str(i + 1), item, folder_path, "FILE_SCRIPT", i) 
                   for i, item in enumerate(files_list)]
    return _enum_items

def get_enum_items(self, context):
    return _enum_items  # Read only

class RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Run Script from Folder"
    bl_idname = "wm.run_script_from_folder"
    
    preset_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="execute",
        description='Select a .py script',
        items=get_enum_items
    )
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        update_enum_items(self, context)
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
       
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, 'preset_enum')
           
    def execute(self, context):
        files_list = update_filelist()
        for item, i in enumerate(files_list, start=1):
            if self.preset_enum == str('OP' + str(item)):
                filepath = join(folder_path, i)
                exec(compile(open(filepath).read(), filepath, 'exec'))
        return {'FINISHED'}    

classes = [RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

How to use class methods for garbled characters.
Another way is to use class methods for update functions and share enumerated items.It means to put "_enum_items" in the same scope.
import bpy 
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir

folder_path = join(bpy.utils.script_paths_pref()[1],"")


def update_filelist():
    allfiles_list = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    files_list = [f for f in allfiles_list if '.py' in f]
    return files_list


def get_enum_items(self, context):
    return RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu._enum_items


class RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Run Script from Folder"
    bl_idname = "wm.run_script_from_folder"
    _enum_items = []  # Global variables are defined only once
    
    preset_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="execute",
        description='Select a .py script',
        items=get_enum_items
    )
        
    @classmethod
    def update_enum_items(cls, context):
        files_list = update_filelist()
        cls._enum_items = [('OP' + str(i + 1), item, folder_path, "FILE_SCRIPT", i) 
                       for i, item in enumerate(files_list)]
        return cls._enum_items


    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.update_enum_items(context)
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
       
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, 'preset_enum')
           
    def execute(self, context):
        files_list = update_filelist()
        for item, i in enumerate(files_list, start=1):
            if self.preset_enum == str('OP' + str(item)):
                filepath = join(folder_path, i)
                exec(compile(open(filepath).read(), filepath, 'exec'))
        return {'FINISHED'}    

classes = [RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()



def get_enum_items(self, context):
    return RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu._enum_items

To increase "code explicitness," we created an external
preset_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name="execute",
    description='Select a .py script',
    items=lambda self, context: RUNSCRIPTFROMFOLDER_OT_PopupMenu._enum_items
)

The same is true for using lambda if you want simplicity in your code.

what do you mean by the script may become heavy?

You probably don't want to do this too much, but it will cause a reload every time you open an enumeration property while the window is open.In the latter case, it's a one-time process without invoke.
